# How to change dynamically created button color in Form1 from Form2 in windowsform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**how to change dynamically createtd button color in form1 from form2 in 
winforms**

Comment: you should describe your problem properly

Comment: i want to change the dynamically created button color in form1 from another form.how to access that dynamic button in form 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Form2**

```
var form = (Form)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
Button _currentBtn = (Button) form.Controls.Find("button_name", true)[0];
_currentBtn.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
```

Comment: thank u @Abi .I solved my issue. The above code is helped me to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

**I solved my Issue .. This is the code**

```
     var form = (Form)Application.OpenForms["Home"];


     Button _currentBtn = (Button) form.Controls.Find("btnMeal", true)[0];


    _currentBtn.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;


    _currentBtn.ForeColor = Color.White;
```